# Uicollectionview controller issue

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

App crash and give following error message
Terminating app due to uncaught exception

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: '-[UICollectionViewController loadView]
 loaded the "RecipeCollectionViewController" nib but didn't get a UICollectionView.
```

Comment: Did you b any chance delete the collectionView from your collectionViewController? Or maybe the view of your collectionViewController isn't connected to your collectionView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a **breakpoint** on:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[ImageCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
```

i would guess your loadView (did you mean viewDidLoad?) method is not being called, so the class is never registered with the collectionView.

Comment: Yes got it i dint not connect the collection view in xib file