# UICollectionView - Porting Storyboard project to no IB project

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, uicollectionview

I found an open source project [(link here)](https://github.com/RobotsAndPencils/RPSlidingMenu) that I need to implement in my next project.
**The problem is that the framework is setup as a storyboard project, which I will not use.** 
I have problems in converting this project to a non-storyboard, non .xib project.
I asked already some help in the comments of [another SA question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250470/ultravisual-iphone-app-like-uiview-or-uitableview-scroll/22395227) and on the [gitpage of this framework](https://github.com/RobotsAndPencils/RPSlidingMenu/issues/20) but time is shrinking.

I keep getting this error:  `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier RPSlidingCellIdentifier - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'` even though the class/nib is registered.

A push in the right direction would be appreciated a lot. I added my test project to my [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l3j2xwntgik2cdd/RPSlidingTRest.zip?dl=0) for your convenience.

The Cell class gets registered in RPSlidingMenuViewController.m viewDidLoad

Comment: If environment tells you `register` class or nib, then try look for `registerClass` or `registerNib` methods in `UICollectionViewController`

Comment: @Jasper Pol code is working fine at my side do check the link for screenshot :----http://postimg.org/image/7lkecl2vx/

Comment: @Aiden you just downloaded my dropbox project and compiled it?

Comment: yes,i just complied it and it's running fine do check the screen shot :added the images too in this -->http://postimg.org/image/w0pwteaib/

Comment: Thats just weird as it crashes when I try to run it.. You use XCode 5.1.1, right?

Comment: @Aiden After clearing Simulator and DerivedData it works now.. Thanks for pointing out it actually was working.. I was searching like a fool on why it did not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Aiden, who pointed out that my project was actually working, I figured out that cleaning out the simulator and /DerivedData was the solution.